# more elegant way to construct SQL adding WHERE and using placeholders

Tags: perl, dbi

What is the best way to construct sql with various number of WHERE conditions ?
My solution looks ugly:

```
my ($where, @values);
if ($phone_number)
{
    $where = 'AND pnone_number=?';
    @values = ($from, $till, $phone_number);
}
else 
{
    $where = '';
    @values = ($from, $till);
}
my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM calls WHERE time between ? AND ? '.$where.' ORDER BY time';
my $res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql, undef, @values) or warn 'error';
```

Comment: SQL::Maker would abstract away the SQL details.

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
my $where = '';
my @values = ( $from, $till );

if ( $phone_number ) { 
    $where = 'AND phone_number=?';
    push @values, $phone_number;
}
```

That eliminates the need for your `else` clause.

You could also use something like [SQL::Abstract](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL::Abstract).

```
use SQL::Abstract;

...

my ( $sql, @values ) = SQL::Abstract->new->select(
    'calls',                                                    # table
    '*',                                                        # columns
    { time => { '<=' => $till, '>' => $from },                  # where clause
      $phone_number ? ( phone_number => $phone_number ) : ( ),
    },
    'time'                                                      # order clause
);
```

Comment: DBIx::Class uses SQL::Abstract under the hood. `$schema->resultset('Calls')->search({ time => {-between, [$from, $until]}, defined $phone ? (phone => $phone) : () }, { order_by => {-asc => 'time'} } )->all`

Answer (score 1):

`1=1` is added for cases when `$where` would be epmty.

```
my $where = "AND time between ? AND ? ";
my @values = ($from, $till);

if ($phone_number) {
    $where .= 'AND pnone_number=? ';
    push @values, $phone_number;
}

my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM calls WHERE 1=1 $where ORDER BY time';
my $res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql, undef, @values) or warn 'error';
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional list-include (aka ["enterprise"](https://metacpan.org/module/perlsecret#Enterprise-x)):

```
my @values = ( $from,
               $till,
               ( $phone_number ) x !! $phone_number,
             );

my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM calls WHERE time between ? AND ? '
        . 'AND phone_number=?' x !! $phone_number
        . ' ORDER BY time';
```

Comment: `"enterprise"` may look good for golfing, but I wouldn't use it otherwise.

Comment: These are the voyages of the Perlship Enterprise, discovering new operators and new syntactations....